# Sort by doesn't sort when includes is used in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I've got a distance attribute in my User model :

```
attr_accessor :distance
```

So when I calculate the distance for each user, and store it in the distance then I can sort them like :

```
users.sort_by!(&:distance)
```

And the users get sorted according to the distance appropriately. But when I include other associated methods i.e :

```
users.includes(:photo).sort_by!(&:distance)
```

This doesn't sort the users at all, why is this? How can I sort it with distance but include association as well?

Comment: Also, you have a default scope? Like this..default_scope order('created_at DESC')

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is your `distance` attribute populated? If it is a calculated value based on other database fields, is it feasible to perform the sorting in the database, rather than in ruby? It may save you some headache, if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `!` in the `sort_by!` method indicates that the object itself is changed rather than returns a different object.
When you call `users.includes(:photo)` this method returns a *different* object. So, what you are actually doing is like:

```
users2 = users.includes(:photo)
users2.sort_by!(&:distance)
```

This is why the users object is not sorted after you call `sort_by!`. A better way to do it might be

```
users = users.includes(:photo).sort_by(&:distance)
```

Comment: You might also want to consider using `order(:distance)` instead, if the `distance` attribute is a field in your table. This will sort the results on the database side.

Comment: @London that's what I was referring to in my comment on the question. Even if the field is calculated from two or more columns, it can still be used in the `.order` / `ORDER BY` clause. You just rewrite the calculation, essentially. Assuming it is indeed calculate from DB columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well it does for me. I do "User", not "users"

```
User.includes(:photo).sort_by!(&:distance)
```

What does "users" variable hold, anyway?. Try User.

Edited with my example, here I user Enquiry for User and Score for Distance.

```
    1.9.3p385 :059 > Enquiry.all.sort_by!(&:score).map &:score
      Enquiry Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `enquiries`.* FROM `enquiries` 
     => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10] 

    1.9.3p385 :060 > Enquiry.includes(:follow_ups).sort_by!(&:score).map &:score
      Enquiry Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `enquiries`.* FROM `enquiries` 
      FollowUp Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `follow_ups`.* FROM `follow_ups` WHERE `follow_ups`.`enquiry_id` IN (55, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 85, 86, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127)
     => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10] 

1.9.3p385 :057 > enquiries = Enquiry.where(status_id: [1,2,3])

    1.9.3p385 :061 > enquiries.includes(:follow_ups).sort_by!(&:score).map &:score
      Enquiry Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `enquiries`.* FROM `enquiries` WHERE `enquiries`.`status_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
      FollowUp Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `follow_ups`.* FROM `follow_ups` WHERE `follow_ups`.`enquiry_id` IN (68, 75, 78, 91, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127)
     => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 10]
```

Note: your question is wrong and you downvote me.

Comment: users = User.where(...) holds users with some conditions

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should do

```
users.sort_by!(&:distance).includes(:photo)
```

Comment: if I do that I get this error `NoMethodError - undefined method `includes' for #<Array:0x0000000c8d09d0>:`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
User.includes(:photo).sort_by!(&:distance)
```

includes is used for Model, not for array.
so User is model name and users is array.

array have 'includes?' method and

Model have 'include' method

So use this

```
 User.includes(:photo).sort_by!(&:distance)
```

instead of

```
users.includes(:photo).sort_by!(&:distance)
```

Comment: dude, users is not array. users = User.where(). So, includes can be used on users.